# Update ListView row Cart Quantity from Codebehind after loading from ViewModel

Tags: c#, forms, xamarin, mvvm

I am loading a huge data from the ViewModel to my Menu (order) page!

You can add products to the Cart on a different page, after the product is added to the Cart. The Menu page is re-activated.

After the page is activated the quantity must be loaded on the menu page (Blue circle with a 2).

How do I update a single row without pre-loading the whole listView in the ViewModel.

I dont want to load the Menu page from the server, just want to add the Cart Item Quantity to the Listview.

How can I update the row in a ListView row.

[ListView Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LzPNu.jpg)

Comment: it would help if you would post the relevant code.  But in general all you need to do is update the relevant properties of the selected item in your model.

Comment: Thank you for responding. Its a lot code to copy. But there is a ObservableCollection<Menu> _menuList that is loading from the server and then its been fill in a ListView. After adding a Item in a Add-Item-Page i need to set the Quantity in the ListView.

Comment: then set the Quantity property on the Menu item

Comment: How do you set the Quantity Property in a ObservableCollection ?

Comment: I assume that each item in the collection has a Quantity property

Comment: Yes it has! Like ProductId, ProductImage, Name, ShopQuantity, IsInShoppingCart its  ObservableCollection<Menu>

Comment: But how can i update the Quantity and IsInShoppingCart (bool) in the  ObservableCollection<Menu> from the ViewModel?

Comment: without seeing your code there is no way I can help you

Comment: private ObservableCollection<Menu> _menuList;

public MenuViewViewModel() : base(listenCultureChanges: true)
{
            LoadData();
}

protected override void OnCultureChanged(CultureInfo culture)
{
            LoadData();
}

public async void LoadData()
{

            IsBusy = true;
            _isLoading = true;
            _isLoaded = false;


                _menuList = GetRestaurantMenuJsonList(_menuJson);



            NotifyAllPropertiesChanged();

            _isLoading = false;
            _isLoaded = true;

}

Comment: that is not really helpful.  I assume that you have an edit page that you use to order an individual item?  And do you pass that page the instance of Menu for the item that you are editing?  Then all you should have to do is update the properties of the Menu item and they should be automatically updated on the Menu page (assuming your Menu class is using INPC)

Comment: No its been updated in a total other Page and its not a property of Menu item. Its a Shopping Cart item that is save in a List<ShoppingCart> _shoppingCart = new List<ShoppingCart>();

Comment: I simply can't help you.  You have what appears to be a fairly complex design but have posted almost no relevant code.  I have no idea what the relationship between your different models are - you've just thrown ShoppingCart into the mix and how that relates to Menu I have no idea.  Your best bet at this point is probably to delete this question and post a new one that includes enough relevant code to understand what you're doing.  My only other suggestion might be to use MessagingCenter to send a message from ShoppingCart to Menu that tells it to update it's Quantity

Comment: Ok! RIght now it works adding the quantity's to the ViewModel but the Quantity's are updated after I scroll down and come back to the listview Row. With a 'NotifyAllPropertiesChanged();'